# Power supply using POE PD

Tags: microcontroller, power-supply, poe

I am designing an embedded system that involves a PIC18F66J65 MCU and a RN677 bluetooth module and passive elements.

The main power source will be module called TPD as POE(power over ethernet) PD (powered device) module which is a module that can provide power to the circute through lan cable. This module has 3 versions, which are :

- TPD-33 output is 3.3Vdc/3.63A.
- TDP-50 output is 5Vdc/2.4A.
- TDP-12 output is 12Vdc/1A.

My questions:

1. Is this a good way of powering the circute instead of normal power supply ?
2. what ampere is enough for the circute which means which module to choose ?
3. is this is a good way in terms of performance to cost ?

Comment: I didn't know [circute's](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Circute) used batteries.

Comment: @HarrySvensson i am sorry i meant power supply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless your module actually uses Ethernet for communications (I don't know why you would use wireless if you are an Ethernet POE device) or you are designing something where POE switches and cable already exist, it is unlikely this is a cost effective way to do things.

You can use a POE PS injector (midspan) without an Ethernet switch to provide power to the ports, but between the midspan injector and the additional device cost this is a quite expensive and innefficient way to power things.

As for which POE module to use, if your circuit operated on 3.3V and requires a reasonably low noise power supply, then the 5V module with a 3.3V LDO will be the best choice of the POE solutions.  More information is needed to make a specific recommendation.

Comment: But dont you think that 2.4A is overcurrent or not ?

Comment: No, the circuit will draw what it needs, the PD current rating is a maximum current.